# Doctrine 1.2 - Accessors not working as expected

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I generated model files successfully, but for some reason I cannot call on known record attributes as if they had concrete accessors, even though I should be able to so via Doctrine_Record::__call(). I checked the [doctrine manual](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/yaml-schema-files.html) for build options but did not see anything relevant to my problem.

```
$conns['core_rw'] = Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://ccast:@127.0.0.1/core', 'core_rw');

Doctrine_Core::generateModelsFromDb('/path/to/lib/Hobis/App/Model', array_keys($conns),
    array(
        'baseClassPrefix'       => 'Base_',     
        'baseClassesDirectory'  => 'Base',
        'classPrefix'       => 'Hobis_App_Model_',
        'classPrefixFiles'      => false,
        'generateBaseClasses'   => true,
        'generateTableClasses'  => true
    )
);
```

After models were generated, I tried this:

```
$conns['core_rw'] = Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://ccast:@127.0.0.1/core', 'core_rw');

$widget = Hobis_App_Model_WidgetTable::getInstance()->findOneById(1337);

// Works
var_dump($widget->get('id'));

// Does not work
var_dump($widget->getId());
```